# Amazon S3: Can clients see the file before upload is complete

Tags: amazon-s3

At [PutObject - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html), I found the following:

> Amazon S3 never adds partial objects; if you receive a success response, Amazon S3 added the entire object to the bucket.

But that's talking about *me* receiving a success response. Am I guaranteed that no *other* client will see the object when listing objects in the bucket -- until the entire object is uploaded?

I want to use S3 as a "spool" directory -- I'll upload files there, and another client will periodically list the files and then download them. I don't want it attempting to download a file that's not completely uploaded.

Comment: This may help: [Discovering and Deleting Incomplete Multipart Uploads to Lower Amazon S3 Costs | AWS Cloud Financial Management](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws-cloud-financial-management/discovering-and-deleting-incomplete-multipart-uploads-to-lower-amazon-s3-costs/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is along the same line as this:

> Amazon S3 never adds partial objects

Until an upload completes, the content that was being uploaded is not technically "in" the bucket.

S3, as you likely know, is not a hierarchical filesystem. It has at least two significant components, the backing store and the index which, unlike in a typical filesystem, are separate... so when you're writing an object, you're not really writing it "in place."   Uploading an object saves the object to the backing store, and *then* adds it to the bucket's index, which is used by `GET` and other requests to fetch the stored data and metadata for retrieval.

With no entry in the index, the object is not accessible.  So you're good.  Downloading an object that hasn't finished uploading yet is impossible.  The object, technically, doesn't yet exist.

Similarly, if an object already exists and you start overwriting it, anyone attempting to download it would get the "old" copy of the object at least until your upload has finished, and this is true even in a bucket without versioning enabled -- overwriting doesn't overwrite the actual object, it overwrites the index entry, and this only happens when the upload is complete.  Note that this mechanism appears to be responsible for the eventual consistency model that applies to `PUT` requests that overwrite existing objects.

---

Note, with regard to data integrity: be sure that whatever you are using upload sets the `Content-MD` request header.  This prevents a corrupted upload by giving S3 a mechanism to detect transmission errors and force a failure if the content being uploaded doesn't match.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. I just found a scenario where I downloaded a file which was still uploading and the download only got the first half. This occurred when using the aws cli `aws s3 cp` command.

Comment: @mekazu that should be impossible, because S3 doesn't even decide whether it will store the object until the upload is complete and passes the `x-amz-content-sha256` (Sig V4) and `Content-MD5` (Sig V4/V2) integrity checks, and until then the object doesn't technically exist. The only idea that comes to mind is that you might want to check your S3 logs to see whether perhaps there's another explanation, such as a prior upload that caught a local file that had only been partially created locally.

Comment: The file in question has a unique name that would not previously exist or be known by any other process than the one downloading it. I reckon the `aws s3 cp` download only copied part of it and I didn't handle the non-zero exit code correctly.

Comment: If `aws s3 cp` is even *able* to do a partial upload that results in an object being created when an error occurs, I would call that a bug in aws-cli.  Which region is the bucket in?