# Snowflake External Table Refresh

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external-tables

Experts,

Have a questions on External Table refresh. We are having a external table pointing to the S3 folders and refresh it manually using Alter command. We have process in Nifi which will place a file in S3 folder and another process in talend which execute the alter command to refresh.

Question Here is - in a time frame Nifi has written 3 files and it is in the middle of writing the fourth file, when i list the S3 it would show 4 file names however the 4th file still being written by Nifi Process. During this time when i execute alter refresh command will 3 files will be refreshed to external table or 4 ? 4th file is still not complete.

Please share your thoughts, Meanwhile we are planning to do a PoC.

Thanks,
Gopi

Comment: There is no such thing as an incomplete file on S3.  S3 is an object store, not a file store.  So, you should not be seeing objects on S3 in a partial load state.  There is some good information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173710/amazon-s3-can-clients-see-the-file-before-upload-is-complete

Comment: Thanks Mike , It helps!!