# What happens to S3 files when updated while already loading a copy?

Tags: file, amazon-s3, copy, file-transfer

I have a service **A** which constantly updates a set of files in an S3 bucket.

More or less, it is equivalent to something like this:

```
while true
do
  generate file
  aws cp s3 <file> <bucket>/<file>
  sleep a little
done
```

I have a service **B** which reads that file once in a while to update the data inside itself. I want a single instance of service **A** while service **B** runs 100 instances.

So service **A** has an equivalent to:

```
while true
do
  aws cp s3 <bucket>/<file> <file>
  update variable holding this data
  sleep a little
done
```

At the moment, the `<file>` name always remains the same. I'm wondering whether this can cause issues. When happens when I upload a file version of the file? Is the old version still available until the copy in service **B** is done, or does the file get overwritten by service **A**?

*i.e. under all operating systems I know of, if I write to a file, a read at the same location sees the new data, not the old one. In other words, in case of a standard OS file, the read may see mangled data (a mix of old and new data).*

Are S3 files the same as standard OS files, or are they safer in this case or not overwritten until an upload is done?

**Note:** I'm particularly interested in having an official S3 document about how this specific case works. My searches have, so far, come empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does AWS S3 GetObject read the partial of the Object being uploaded to s3 at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379940/does-aws-s3-getobject-read-the-partial-of-the-object-being-uploaded-to-s3-at-the)

Comment: @AnonCoward Oh! So it's using multipart download and that's why my file is broken. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the [Amazon S3 User Guide in the Consistency Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html#ConsistencyModel).

Here is the pertinent paragraph:

> Updates to a single key are atomic. For example, if you make a PUT request to an existing key from one thread and perform a GET request on the same key from a second thread concurrently, you will get either the old data or the new data, but never partial or corrupt data.

This clearly says that the data you `GET` will not be overwritten as in the case of a standard file. You also won't know whether it is the old or new instance (unless you define some metadata or have a date or serial number in the file).

However, when dealing with large files, the API [automatically switches to multi-part uploads](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/) and that means you may end up copying part of the old file and parts of the new file. To avoid the issue, you must make sure to do a copy without using multiparts.

Comment: Multi-part uploads has nothing to do with why a download may get results from two different versions of an object.

Comment: @AnonCoward Would you be so kind as to offer a copy answer, then? Having the correct answer would be best.

Comment: This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379940/does-aws-s3-getobject-read-the-partial-of-the-object-being-uploaded-to-s3-at-the) answers the core question.