# Is minio.GetObject() automatically using multipart to download large files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, multipart, minio

We have a generator process that creates new files, one of which is over 6Gb in size.

The consumer process reads those files *in parallel* ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72385934)).

Testing with `aws s3 cp ...` from my computer, I pretty much always get a mangled file—a file with some of the old data and some of the new data—because my Internet connection is too slow to download the whole file in one go.

This happens because the [copy command uses the multipart feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379940).

Our consumer process, though, is written in Go and it uses [`GetObject()` from minio library](https://docs.min.io/docs/golang-client-api-reference.html#GetObject). Reading the documentation and doing searches does not mention anything about using multipart on a `GetObject()`. It clearly gives you the option on a [`PutObject()`](https://docs.min.io/docs/golang-client-api-reference.html#PutObject):

> ```
> minio.PutObjectOptions
> ```
>
> Pointer to struct that allows user to set optional custom metadata, content-type, content-encoding, content-disposition, content-language and cache-control headers, pass encryption module for encrypting objects, and **optionally configure number of threads for multipart put operation**.

Is the `GetObject()` automatically using multipart when downloading large files?

Here are the basic lines of code that we use to read the data, without all the error handling and such:

```
mc, _ := minio.New(s3Endpoint, &minio.Options{})

s3, _ := mc.GetObject(ctx, bucket, filename,
                              minio.GetObjectOptions{})

var data map[string]SomeStruct
json.NewDecoder(s3.reader).Decode(&data)
```

Comment: GetObject returns a stream so it depends on how you're reading the stream - do you have any sample code please?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I added a sample. There isn't much to it, but hopefully that can help.