# File Watcher for S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to figure out how can I develop something like the C# FileSystemWatcher, but with an AWS S3 bucket. I've read that I can use AWS Lambda, SNS or SQS, and have S3 trigger any of the those services when a object is created.

I have a desktop app, in which I need to get notified when a file is created or deleted in the S3 bucket. How can AWS connect to my app in real time? Sorry if I'm putting it very simply but I'm learning as I go and I have no ideia how a remote service can access your code or app.

Comment: Do you only have one single instance of your app that should be notified at any time? If so: S3 => SQS for the notifications and then have your application perform a long-polling on the SQS queue, delete the message immediately and do something according to the notification. If you want multiple application to receive the notification: have a publicly reachable HTTP endpoint on every client (unlikely to work) or alternative set up websockets, e.g. via api gateway and have each client use the websocket and let S3 => Lambda put a message int the websockets. Nothing of this is trivial to build.

Comment: There will be more than one instance, each instance/user will have access to one object inside the bucket. So each object would notify only the instance that is "connected" to it. In this case, SQS option would work? If every instance performs a long-polling, when there is a message every instance will read it, but only the correct one will use it. Could this be viable?

Comment: Maybe maybe maybe with SQS FIFO and the MessageGroupId being the userid.

Comment: How critical is it you perform an action the instant the file is available?  If it's not that critical, you could just optimistically try, and keep trying every minute or so till S3 no longer returns an 404 error.

Comment: To be honest, instantaniously would be the goal. By trying, you mean listing the object and check for changes? I'm comparing files, locally and on S3, and check for changes

Comment: The method I will try: send message when S3 event triggers (problem that many objects might be triggered). Message will be caught by all instances. The message will be formated to retrieve the key name; if it matches the user, the message will be processed and deleted. Processing consists of listing the objects in S3 and comparing wtih the local files.

Comment: *"Message will be caught by all instances."* - that is not how SQS works, *one* instance will see the message. And if you then decide the message is not for the instance the message will become visible in the queue after the visibility timeout expires. This does not scale well at all. Going with a trial-and-error approach in SQS is not the way to go. If you want SQS use SQS FIFO with the right message group ids but even that might fail.

Comment: "check for changes"  Be very careful with that.  S3 is strongly consistent, but there are still cases where a download of an object can [get two different versions of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379940/does-aws-s3-getobject-read-the-partial-of-the-object-being-uploaded-to-s3-at-the/68382734#68382734) if it changes out from under it.

Answer (score 0):

one option that I can suggest is to:

1. create a lambda that triggered by S3.
2. create a http listener on your desktop app that will listen on some port XXXX
3. send a wget command from the lambda to some ip/dns name on port XXXX

security alert: better to have some kind of handshake or at lease some certification to deny option to ping your http server from malicious sources

Prerequisite:
your desktop app to have some static ip / dns name that can be reached from the internet.

a way to bypass this in case you are in a private net that cannot be reached from outside, is to create a jumpbox in the cloud and to open a tunnel from your desktop app to the ec2 in the cloud.