# AWS S3 File copy & download

Tags: amazon-s3

Consider this scenario: in Amazon S3, a new version of a file is being uploaded, and, simultaneously, the request to download the same file is being executed. What does the user get in this scenario?

The older version of the file (or) The new version of the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does AWS S3 GetObject read the partial of the Object being uploaded to s3 at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379940/does-aws-s3-getobject-read-the-partial-of-the-object-being-uploaded-to-s3-at-the)

Answer (score 0):

Since all uploads to Amazon S3 are atomic, the user gets the older file version in this scenario. They get the latest version of the file only if the upload is complete. It never gives an incomplete or corrupt version of the file.

Comment: This isn't quite right, [it is possible in this scenario to get a corrupt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379940/does-aws-s3-getobject-read-the-partial-of-the-object-being-uploaded-to-s3-at-the/68382734#68382734).